# Singular versus plural verb with ratios: 1 in 8 adults have/has X

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should I use a singular or plural verb form after a ratio?

*About 1 in 4 adults drink/drinks more alcohol than is recommended for good health.
*About 1 in 8 adults have/has an alcohol use disorder.

I have not been able to find a clear answer in any grammar style guides. I have found examples of both singular and plural verbs used on different websites (e.g., CDC, Johns Hopkins, NAMI).

Comment: You may find conflicting style guides; is there one that is generally used in your field?

Comment: I think I would use the plural form there. They are clearly not talking about "1" in 1 in 4, but of many, 25% of all adults. Also, the phrase could be "3 in 10 adults drink to excess". I don't think I would adjust the number of the verb for the scaling of the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "1 in 8" is a proportion.  It does not refer to one person in a literal group of 8 people, but to one-eighth of the population. It, therefore, refers to a plurality of people and would be treated as plural:

> 1 in 8 adults drink too much.

Answer (score 0):

"One" is the subject of the sentence; therefore, the verb must be singular.  To simplify...

- "One drinks more alcohol than is recommended for good health."
- "One adult drinks more alcohol than is recommended for good health."

I found a [nice blog post](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/10/patently-singular.html) with more examples.